# SVN global ignores is not working (solutions from other posts are not working)

Tags: svn

I go into my .subversion/config and add .settings, but from an `svn diff`, we see it is not working.

```
~/Space/ifp-integration/CIGNA-IFP-ESB$ svn diff
Index: .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
===================================================================
--- .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs    (revision 2014)
+++ .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs    (working copy)
@@ -1,6 +1,15 @@
```

This shows someone must have checked it in, but I don't care as I want to ignore it either way. Is there a way to make sure this is ignored?

Comment: On Windows, file `config` is `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config`. E.g. `C:\Documents and Settings\Peter\Application Data\Subversion\config`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't ignore stuff that's in your repository. That's not how ignores work in Subversion.

Ignoring is simply a way to prevent **accidentally** ***adding*** a file to the repository. If a file already exists in the repository, you can't ignore it.

Global ignores only apply to files and not to directories. If you say ignore `.settings` in your Subversion configuration file, it will not ignore a directory called `.settings`, but only a file called `.settings`. And, it will only ignore the `.settings` file if it isn't already in the repository.

Basically, if you say `svn add *` or `svn status`, any files that are not in the repository, and that match your global ignore patter will not be added shown in `svn status`. That's all it does.

You can create a property on a directory called `svn:ignore` that is similar. However, `svn:ignore` will also ignore directories too. For example, if you have a Maven project, you can set `svn:ignore` = `target`, and the target folder won't be reported on. However, the `svn:ignore` only works for the directory where the property is on, and not subdirectories.

So how can you ignore the `.settings` directory? Simple: You don't check it out. Unfortunately, there's no simple way of doing this in Subversion. Here's what you can do:

```
$ svn checkout --depth=immediates http://server/src/myproj
```

This will check out all of the folders and files in your working directory, but not any sub directories. In Kornshell, and BASH (if you set `shopt -s extglob`):

```
$ svn update --set-depth=infinity !(.settings)
```

This will continue your checkout in all of your directories except for the `.settings` directory.

You can also do this:

```
$ svn update --set-depth=exclude .settings
```

to remove the `.settings` directory once it has already been checked out. This won't remove the `.settings` directory from the repository, but it will remove the `.settings` directory from your working directory, and `svn diff` on your working directory (but not the repository URL) will not report back anything in the `.settings` directory.

One big important point I need to emphasize: Ignore only prevent the ***accidental*** addition of a file into your repository. It doesn't prevent someone from adding it, and once it's there, it won't be ignored.

Also, your global ignore settings are not global to everyone. Just to you. If you want to prevent people from adding files that shouldn't be added to the repository, you'll need a pre-commit hook like [this one](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook).

This hook can be used to prevent files or directories with particular names from being committed, and it can also be used to make sure that properties on files and directories are set. For example, you may want to make sure that people can't add in a `.settings` directory in your projects. Or that `svn:ignore` property on the directory is set to ignore the `.settings` directory.